# Android WallpaperManager setBitmap fitCenter

Tags: android, image, bitmap, image-resizing

I'm trying to use WallpaperManager to FIT CENTER a bitmap to the wallpaper of my phone.

- Image size: 3840 x 2160
- Phone size: 1080 x 1920

**I've tried numerous strategies:**

1. myWallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
2. Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mImage, width, height, true);
3. [Set Wallpaper with bitmap avoid crop and set fit center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699168/set-wallpaper-with-bitmap-avoid-crop-and-set-fit-center)
4. [how to fit the whole image on screen as wallpaper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408179/how-to-fit-the-whole-image-on-screen-as-wallpaper)
5. [Wallpaper not properly fit on device screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759358/wallpaper-not-properly-fit-on-device-screen)
6. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html
7. http://androidexample.com/How_to_Set_WallPaper_in_Android/question_answer.php?view=qad&token=39

### Every time I get a weird bitmap that doesn't fit center, does anyone have any suggestions?

**What I want it to look like:**
[image]

**Image info:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer: [Scaled Bitmap maintaining aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440647/scaled-bitmap-maintaining-aspect-ratio)

What I did was this:

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int phoneHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    int phoneWidth = metrics.widthPixels;

    Bitmap mBit = returnBitmap(mImage, phoneWidth, phoneHeight);

private Bitmap returnBitmap(Bitmap originalImage, int width, int height){
    Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)width, (int)height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    float originalWidth = originalImage.getWidth();
    float originalHeight = originalImage.getHeight();

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);

    float scale = width / originalWidth;

    float xTranslation = 0.0f;
    float yTranslation = (height - originalHeight * scale) / 2.0f;

    Matrix transformation = new Matrix();
    transformation.postTranslate(xTranslation, yTranslation);
    transformation.preScale(scale, scale);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);

    canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, transformation, paint);

    return background;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, After Searching for a week to set a wallpaper that fits the screen, Now I Found this Answer. Thank you very much. It helped me a lot.